# Finding all red text in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-interop

I am trying to figure out how to find all red text in a word file (and then delete it). However, it seems I am at a dead end. Could someone please help me get on the right direction?

This is what I have so far:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object readOnly = false;
        object isVisible = true;
        object fileName = "D:\\word.docx";

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        Document document = application.Documents.Open(@"D:\word2.docx",missing,true,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing,missing);

        FindAndReplace(application, "", "");
    }

    private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application doc, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        //options
        object matchCase = false;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundsLike = false;
        object matchAllWordForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = true;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiacritics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        doc.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting();
        doc.Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        doc.Selection.Find.Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed;

        //execute find and replace
        doc.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText, ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
            ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundsLike, ref matchAllWordForms, ref forward, ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText, ref replace,
            ref matchKashida, ref matchDiacritics, ref matchAlefHamza, ref matchControl);
    }
```

When I run this, I get a COM exception saying that

> the command is not available.

Comment: And which line of code is triggering the error??? Since you're running this on `Selection` what is actually selected when the document is opened?

Comment: The doc.Selection.Find.Execute is triggering the error. I have tried running it on the document while having a selection made. However, since the goal is to run this through the entire content of the word file, we can use another object instead of the Selection.

Comment: Maybe the document is protected from editing. That's the typical case when you get such an error. What is the value of `doc.ProtectionType`?

Comment: Actually (also @PeterWolf) the error means that Word is unable to execute the command in the current configuration. In my experience, when. using `Selection`, it's because the command is invalid where the selection currently is. Ondrej, you might try with a `Range` object. For example Word.Range rngFind = document.Content;` - note you need the `document` object instantiated when the file is opened, not the `Application` object.

Comment: I can confirm what Cindy said - thanks for that. Switching to the Range object helped, I am now able to run the code. 

Still, it seems to me that it would be better to have more of a control of what's happening with the found text - not just simple find and replace en masse - I would need to respond e.g. to finding occurences of this in headings, etc. Is there any way to iterate through individual occurences of red text?